# Use Case: Append text to JTextField by double clicking the items in JList

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield, jlist

I have 2 JTextFields (JTextField1 and JTextField2) to which text has to appended from JList. [image]

Use case is, after I finish typing in JTextField1 and double click the arguement in Jlist, it has to be appended to the JTextField1 since that was the last area of focus from the keyboard. The same case with JTextField2.

Code:

```
jTextField1.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {

public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) 
{
    if (lista1.size()>0)
       {
        MouseListener mouseListener2 = new MouseAdapter() 
         {          
        @Override
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) 
          {

           JList varList = (JList) mouseEvent.getSource();
           if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) 
                {                        
                 int index = varList.locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());
                 if (index >= 0) 
                   {
                    Object o2 = varList.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                    String prefClassLabel =  jTextField1.getText().trim();   

                    jTextField1.setText("test" );                                     
                    }  
                }
           }

         };
         argVariables_List.addMouseListener(mouseListener2);
      }       

    }
    });
```

I wrote an exact similar function for jTextField2. But still when I double click the text from the jList, it gets appended to both the jTextFields instead of the last focussed jTextField. Please suggest me on what is the mistake.

Comment: Start by writing a single `MouseListener` to detect the double click.  Use a common `FocusListener` to detect which field is currently active and maintain a reference to it

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried that.                                                                 `public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                System.out.println(evt.getComponent().getName());`                            getting null.

Comment: @vikky2405, Keep all the information in one place so everybody knows what has been suggested. You got the same advice here as you got in the other posting. Nobody has said anything about adding a MouseListener to the JList in the FocusListener.

Comment: @camickr I am not able to understand how to add a common focusListener for both the textfield and fetch the one it is pointing to.

Comment: So why start a new topic? You said you would follow up in the original question which is the proper approach so everybody knows what has been suggested. In any case you were given a solution that doesn't require you to use a FocusListener.